# Is it possible to pass arguments in lotus notes dialog box

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have one form with two fields called "Field 1" and "Field 2" and one action button called "check". On click of that action button, i want to open dialog box with three fields which should get auto populate based on Field 2 value. How to achieve it?

Appreciate if anyone helps me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There's a `document` parameter for `NotesUIWorkspace.DialogBox()`. Use this document to pass parameters to your dialog.

---

**UPDATE**

Assume you have a form with name "MyDialogForm" to represent your dialog.

It looks like that and contains 3 fields:

[image: MyDialogForm]

And you have a form with two fields and "Check" button:

[image: TestForm]

Put the following code to the "Click" event handler of your "Check" button:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Const DIALOG_FORM_NAME = "MyDialogForm"

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim dialogBoxAccepted As Boolean
    Dim dialogParamDoc As NotesDocument

    Dim currentDocument As NotesDocument    
    Dim field2Value As String

    Set currentDocument = ws.CurrentDocument.Document 
    field2Value = currentDocument.GetItemValue("Field2")(0)

    'document created in-memory, but should not be saved
    Set dialogParamDoc = New NotesDocument(currentDocument.ParentDatabase)

    'populating dialog box fields
    Call dialogParamDoc.ReplaceItemValue("DialogField1", "dialogField1 with: " + field2Value)
    Call dialogParamDoc.ReplaceItemValue("DialogField2", "dialogField2 with: " + field2Value)
    Call dialogParamDoc.ReplaceItemValue("DialogField3", "dialogField3 with: " + field2Value)

    dialogBoxAccepted = ws.DialogBox(DIALOG_FORM_NAME,True , True, False, False  , False , False, "My Dialog Title", dialogParamDoc, True)
    If dialogBoxAccepted Then
        'displaying values, entered/changed in dialog box
        Msgbox dialogParamDoc.getItemValue("DialogField1")(0),,"DialogField1"
        Msgbox dialogParamDoc.getItemValue("DialogField2")(0),,"DialogField2"
        Msgbox dialogParamDoc.getItemValue("DialogField3")(0),,"DialogField3"
    End If
End Sub
```

This code reads "Field2" and populates dialog fields based on its value. Then it shows the dialog where you can change these values.

[image: demo dialog]

If you pressed OK in your dialog (dialog accepted), the code will show the values you have altered in dialog box.

Comment: Can you say it elaborately pls? because im new to this technology

Comment: @Sathish check my update please. I think it answers to your question.

Comment: Very good answer. But I don't agree with the "Please note" sentence at the end: If you just set the fourth parameter of DialogBox to "False" instead of "True" as in your example, then it will also return newly created fields, as the documentation states: `noNewFields: Boolean. Optional. Specify True to not add fields that are on the dialog box form but not already contained in the underlying document. Otherwise, all dialog box fields are passed to the underlying document.
`

Comment: @TorstenLink yes, you're right. Fixed my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Sathish you are welcome :) Please accept the answer (green mark below answer upwote/downvote arrows), to help other users to find this answer later.

Comment: If you don't want to create a new doc for this, you can also pass in parameters via notessession.setEnvironmentVar and notessession.getEnviromentString (or formula equivalent). I have done this to good effect, setting an enviromnment variable to a web query-string-like value eg "docpos=1&hasNext=true&hasPrev=false". Set that on the calling design element, and get the variable when in the dialogbox.

Comment: @user2808054 from my point of view, use of notes.ini variables is a last-ditch method and I discourage use of this approach if there's another way. It is easy to forget clean up afterwards, and notes.ini gets populated/polluted with unnecessary and even confidential information.

Comment: I agree with confidentiality, but the other points are a matter of opinion. Regarding polluting notes.ini: Easily got around by always beggining your variable names with a known prefix, so you know whcih ones to clean up should you feel the urge. Not that one variable makes a heck of a difference.