# How to pass back values from dialog box to parent form again in lotus notes client

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have a new form with fields called Field 1,Field 2 and one button. On click of that button, dialog box will display with some radio buttons. here i want to pass the selected radio button values to Field 2.

How to achieve it?
Appreciate if anyone help me out.
In dialog box, it looks like below[image]
[image]

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688147/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-in-lotus-notes-dialog-box/36688540#36688540

Comment: thanks Rafael. but that question asked for to pass from form to dialog box. here i want to pass the value from dialog box to form

Comment: in my answer by that link, there is an example, how to pass information to the dialog box and how to read the information from dialog box when it is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just **name** your dialog box's radio button field **the same** like your target field in form (Field 2 in your case) and make sure

- you don't use `[NOFIELDUPDATE]` option in [@DialogBox](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX.html?lang=en)
- parameter `noFieldUpdate` is *not* set to `True` in [notesUIWorkspace .DialogBox()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX_METHOD.html?lang=en).

Comment: what about if i want to populate multiple selection of radio button value to Field 2

Comment: Then create a field Field 2 in dialog box which collects data of radio button fields with formula "@Trim(radioButton1: radioButton2)"

Comment: No its not updating in the target field but i got the selected values in Field 2 where i created in dialog box

Comment: Make sure your radio buttons have set option "Refresh fields on keyword change".

Comment: yes its enabled, but not working. do we need to make that dialog box form type as response?

Comment: No, the dialog box uses a "normal" form. The field Field2 in dialog box has to be of type "Computed" and field Field2 in main form is "Computed" too with the formula `@ThisValue` or "Editable".

Comment: Both fields Field 2 in dialog box and main form are computed with @Trim(Field2). Main form also is in edit mode.

Comment: in On click of "OK" button, i'm checking what are the radio buttons are checked, based on that I'm taking the corresponding Names (which is in first column) and replacing it to "Field 2" field (which is resides in dialog box). Once replacing it, i'm doing computewithform to reflect those names in Field 2.

Comment: You don't need any code in onclick event. Just calculate corresponding names in computed field Field2 in dialog box and don't call computewithform as this causes in many time side effects.

Comment: sorry knut my mistake. i have custom button in that dialog box. its not default "Ok" button thats y i'm computing. I will update the same in question

Comment: Please show button's code and dialog box in Designer as image instead of dialog's image second time...

Comment: Its in other VM knut, Im in a situation where not able to show you

Comment: Just a last advise: create a simple working example based on my tips and go from there until it breaks. Then you know what causes the error. Good luck!

Comment: I resolved the problem knut. i gave uiworkspace.refreshparentnote in Upload button after i replaced selected employers into Field 2. After calling dialog box, i gave uidoc.reload to get those values into main form

Comment: always your suggestion and answers help me a lot. thanks knut